# appending text in textarea with hotkeys and javascript

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

I have 4 input text tags and 4 textarea tags and I need to create some hotkey like Ctrl+n, Ctrl+r and Ctrl+o to append predefined words at the cursor position for all text fields.

I got this script but is only for onclick event, so I want just to show just one time for the user the text (Press Ctrl+n for word1, Ctrl+r for word2 and Ctrl+o for word3) then he can insert those words every time he is typing some text whatever the field he is.

```
    <script>
    function addText(event) {
    var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("txt1").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;
    }
    </script>
    <div onclick="addText(event)">word1</div>
    <div onclick="addText(event)">word2</div>
    <div onclick="addText(event)">word3</div>

        <label><b>Text 1: </b></label><br>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="80" id = "txt1" name="txt1"></textarea>

        <label><b>Text2: </b></label>
        <input type="text" size="69" name="txt2" value="">
```

Comment: [Don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have a demented scope chain, require global pollution, and have quote escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this.
Please note that I've used underused keys on purpose since certain control key combinations are reserved for browser usage only and cannot be intercepted by the client side JavaScript in the web page (like `ctrl+N` or `ctrl+T`).

```js
const arrKey = ['a', 'l', 'b'],
  arrVal = ['addedA', 'addedL', 'addedB'];

function addText(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("addtext")) {
    const index = arrKey.indexOf(event.key);
    if (event.ctrlKey && index != -1) {
      event.preventDefault();
      insertAtCaret(event.target, arrVal[index]);
    }
  }
}

function insertAtCaret(el, text) {
  const caretPos = el.selectionStart,
    textAreaTxt = el.value,
    newCaretPos = caretPos + text.length;

  el.value = textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + text + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos);
  el.setSelectionRange(newCaretPos, newCaretPos);
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', addText);
```

```html
<label><b>Text 1: </b></label><br>
<textarea placeholder="Try ctrl+a or ctrl+b" rows="10" cols="40" id="txt1" name="txt1" class="addtext"></textarea><br/>
<label><b>Text 2: </b></label><br/>
<input type="text" size="40" name="txt2" class="addtext" value=""><br/>
<label><b>Text 3: </b></label><br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="txt3" name="txt1" class="addtext"></textarea><br/>
<label><b>Text 4: </b></label><br/>
<input type="text" size="40" name="txt4" class="addtext" value="">
```

Comment: Sorry, but is adding only in the end of text. Can you tell how to append any place where is the cursor? Thanks

Comment: @KonradSoares You're welcome :). Answer edited to insert at the caret position, and restore the position after the appended text.